# How to filter multiple properties of one array of object from the other array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to solve the problem in which i have to apply multiple filters to the array of object. Let suppose I am having a larger array of object which contains the configuration property which is further an object. On other side i have small  object which are the ones the user chooses to filter(based on the checkboxes). i want to compare objects made with the parent array of objects by selecting multiple values.

So in the image the user chooses multiple values(using check boxes) and based on that he needs to filter the main array of objects.So after checking the checkboxes i get **childObject** and i have to filter **parentArray** on the basis of that..... please help me with this:

```js
childobject = 
  {'Bathroom': '[2,1]',
  'Bedroom': '[3,2]',
  'halfBathroom':'0',
  'name':'[2BD-2BA,2BD-2BA-1]'}



parentArray = [
0:{},
1:{},
2:{
  'property1':'____',
  'property2':'_____',
  'configuration':'{
   bathroom: 2
  bedroom: 2
  created_at: "2019-03-08 20:52:52"
  created_by: 264
  half_bathroom: 1
  id: 26
  is_selected: 0
  name: "2BD-2BA-1/2BA"
  name_en: "2BD-2BA-1/2BA"
  name_es: "2RE-2BA-1/2BA"
  status: 1
  updated_at: "2019-08-23 05:39:44"
  }'
  }
  3: {},
  4:{}
]
```

Comment: Your childArray  is not a proper array and it is even any object (because of double prperty name):

Comment: What are the filtercriteria? All of them had to be fullfilled or only some. Only objects with exact property-values (e.g. bedroom==2)? Give us a result, how it should looks like.

Comment: Yes, whatever we choose we have to filter on all of them. I am not able to write code with multiple filters.

Comment: If there is an array in the filter-values than both values are accepted?

Comment: @Deepak007 your code contains errors childArray  &&  parentArray  is not an object or array. Did you mixed brackets and you wanted to use `{}` over `[]` to wrap content of childArray  &&  parentArray ?

Comment: I suppose childArray  should be an object (with `{}`) and parentArray should be an array without the `0:`, `1:`, ...  but this had the OP to tell us.

Comment: @KrzysztofKaczyński problem updated.  I have to compare the childobject with the configration object present in each object inside the array.

Comment: @Deepak007 does `parentArray` should look like that `parentArray = [{}, {}, {}]` ?

Comment: I supposed it in my sollution so, because tht make the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the datastructure at some points:

- You had different key in child and parent (upper/lowercase + camelcase/_ writing)
- Some Missing `}` in the parent.
- In child quotationmarks for integer deleted.Missing `,` added.
- Changing some values in cruiteria, so that there is a result.
- In parent delting of 0:, 1:, 2:, 3:, 4: to get a valid array.

```js
childArray = {
  'bathroom': [2,1],
  'bedroom': [3,2],
  'half_bathroom':1,
  'name':['2BD-2BA', '2BD-2BA-1/2BA']
};

parentArray = [
 {},
 {},
 {
  'property1':'____',
  'property2':'_____',
  'configuration':{
     bathroom: 2,
     bedroom: 2,
     created_at: "2019-03-08 20:52:52",
     created_by: 264,
     half_bathroom: 1,
     id: 26,
     is_selected: 0,
     name: "2BD-2BA-1/2BA",
     name_en: "2BD-2BA-1/2BA",
     name_es: "2RE-2BA-1/2BA",
     status: 1,
     updated_at: "2019-08-23 05:39:44"
  },
 },
 {},
 {}
]
let res = parentArray.filter(elem => Object.entries(childArray).every(([key,val]) => {
    let conf = elem.configuration;
    
    if (conf===undefined) return false;
    
    if (typeof(val) === 'object') {
        return val.some(crit => crit===conf[key]);
    } else {
        return val===conf[key];
    }
}));

console.log(res);
```